# How to find out if *char string ends with ".abc"

Tags: c

I have got something already passed to these vars:

```
char *filename;
int filename_len;
```

How do I check if `filename` ends with ".abc"?

Comment: I've tried something like this, but it causes segfaults in my aplication in some cases. I don't really know what is comming in filename and this must work in every situation         

        char *loglog_ext;
        loglog_ext = strrchr(filename, '.');
        if(strcmp(loglog_ext, ".abc") == 0)

Answer (score 11):

```
if (filename_len >= 4 && strcmp(filename + filename_len - 4, ".abc") == 0) {
  // match
}
```

Comment: What if `filename_len` is less than 4?

Comment: What if `filename_len` is equal to 4?

Comment: The conditional you crafted is `filename_len > 4`. Four is not greater than four, thus the conditional is false. Thus it does not match under your conditional.

Comment: I should probably repeat primary school or go to sleep, or both

Comment: @Kveri, don't worry. We all had our blunders. Just move on.

Comment: @Kay, I think you mean `memcmp(3)`.

Comment: Can use strcmpi for case insensitive comparison